# Loop through array of elements, replace html with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where each row contains several ratings, 5 of which need to be blanked when a certain action is taken and then the original rating put back in the  when another action is taken. I've stored the original word in data, so my original line in HTML looks like this.

```
echo "<td data-Rating = $Rating class = 'outfieldlineuprating'>$Rating</td>";
```

In my JS, I find all the elements with 'outfieldlineuprating' like so..

```
SkillRatings = PlayerRow.find('.outfieldlineuprating');
```

It works up to this point (PlayerRow is fine). I know it works because when taking the first action (i.e blanking the elements), it works with ..

```
SkillRatings.html('----');
```

This puts ---- in all of the 5 elements with the 'outfieldlineuprating' class. Reversing it however, I'm struggling with. 'SkillRatings' at this point presumably contains some sort of array of the relevant td's, but I don't know how to loop through it, extract the data and insert that into the html. Here's what I'm trying but this doesn't work in JS.

```
for (var index = 0; index < SkillRatings.length; index++){
    Rating = SkillRatings[index].attr('data-Rating');
    SkillRatings[index].html(Rating);
}
```

This just gives the error : SkillRatings[index].attr is not a function

Comment: This is also a Jquery question. Can you add that tag as well?

Comment: Looks your code use jQuery, if is so try: `$(SkillRatings[index]).attr`.

Comment: Oops yeah, it's JQuery. Errr, I'll try to add the tag.

Comment: Also thanks Mario, that fixed it. I need to swat up on the syntax of JQuery because I had it right apart from the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using jQuery and `SkillRatings = PlayerRow.find('.outfieldlineuprating');` creates a jQuery object containing the elements.

`SkillRatings[index]` returns an actual element, not the jQuery object for that element

You would need to change `SkillRatings[index].jQueryMethod()` to

```
SkillRatings.eq(index).jQueryMethod(); 
// or 
$(SkillRatings[index]).jQueryMethod();
```

However this is easier done using `SkillRatings.each` which exposes `this` as the current element in the loop

Instead of using `for` loop try

```
SkillRatings.each(function(){
     // "this" is current element
     $(this).html( $(this).data('Rating'));
});
```

Comment: OK...there is a mismatch in question then between `data-RatingData` and `data-Rating` shown in your html.

Comment: Yes you're right. Have updated question. Your answer is correct and the loop works. Thanks :)